# Calculate similarity matrix using the tm package

Tags: r, matrix, tm

I need to create a similarity matrix, and the code below is what I have so far. However, the results are not what I need. The code returns a matrix that has 16 rows, which is the product of the 8 unique terms in the document-term matrix and the 2 unique terms in the workTitle.

What I need is a matrix that has only 4 rows (one per title), and each row to represent the sum of the edit distance between each word in the workTitle and each of the terms in titles.

```
require(tm)

workTitle <- c("biomechanical engineer")
titles <- c("train machinist", "operations supervisor", "pharmacy tech", "mechanical engineer")

# create Corpus and a document-term matrix from the titles
titleCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(titles))
titleDtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(titleCorpus)

# print out the document-term matrix
inspect(titleDtm)

# calculate edit distance between every word from the test_var and the column names in the document-term matrix
d <- apply(titleDtm, 1, function(x) {
  terms <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(workTitle), " "))
  adist(colnames(titleDtm), terms)
})
```

**This is the output from the code above:**

```
       Docs
         1  2  3  4
   [1,] 11 11 11 11
   [2,]  8  8  8  8
   [3,]  3  3  3  3
   [4,]  9  9  9  9
   [5,] 11 11 11 11
   [6,] 11 11 11 11
   [7,] 10 10 10 10
   [8,] 11 11 11 11
   [9,]  0  0  0  0
  [10,]  7  7  7  7
  [11,]  8  8  8  8
  [12,]  9  9  9  9
  [13,]  8  8  8  8
  [14,]  8  8  8  8
  [15,]  7  7  7  7
  [16,]  6  6  6  6
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, how about something like:

```
terms <- as.character(Dictionary(titleDtm))
dat <- data.frame(adist(titles, terms), row.names = titles)
colnames(dat) <- terms
dat
```

Which results in

```
                       engineer machinist mechanical operations pharmacy supervisor tech train
 train machinist             12         6         11         12       11         14   12    10
 operations supervisor       16        17         18         11       18         11   19    17
 pharmacy tech               12        10         11         11        5         13    9    11
 mechanical engineer         11        13          9         16       16         16   16    16
```

And then for the sums

```
data.frame(sum = rowSums(dat))
```

Which has the following output

```
                      sum
train machinist        88
operations supervisor 127
pharmacy tech          82
mechanical engineer   113
```